# Updating R and RScript in the command line to match newly installed version

Tags: r, terminal, command-line

I had a difficult time searching for an answer on this, so I thought I'd reach out here for help. I updated R to 4.2.1 and update RStudio as well, but I found that the R in my mac's terminal is still using the old version (3.5.1). Does anyone know why this might be and how I can change the R and Rscript command in my terminal to be using the latest version of R?

Thank you :)

Comment: The terminal uses the `PATH` environment variable to locate commands.  You need to find which of your startup files are setting `PATH` to point to the wrong version of R.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I've always been confused when it comes to changing or setting `PATH` and haven't found simple clear explanations on it. This is from `echo $PATH`.

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/CarlCarl/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/CarlCarl/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin`

Comment: You might find where yours is set using `grep PATH ~/.* -d skip` .  Mine is set in `.bash_profile`, but maybe you're not using `bash`.  You can find where R is found using `which -a R`.

Answer (score 0):

I might have just found a workaround.

Instead of running `R` or `Rscript`, I can run `/usr/local/bin/R` or `/usr/local/bin/Rscript`. This will load the most recent version of `R`/`Rscript`.

Comment: This indicates that `/usr/local/bin` should appear in your `PATH` before the path to the old version of R.

Answer (score 0):

Using the feedback from *user2554330*'s comment, I added the following to my `.bash_profile`.

```
# Setting PATH for R 4.2.1 
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Then I ran `source ~/.bash_profile`. Now `R` and, I assume `Rscript`, run the correct version.

I still find the `PATH` variable confusing tbh, but this problem is solved at least.

Thanks *user2554330*!

Edit: I should mention that `/usr/local/bin/R/` is an alias that points to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/bin/R`, which is how I found this path for `R`. Same for `Rscript`.

Comment: It's usually a good practice to use the alias directory in the `PATH` variable, because R will be at a different location the next time you upgrade it.  However, I see from your other comment that you already have that there, so you must also have the old R in an earlier location.